# Datagridview: Get column name by right clicking on column header (read info)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have two datagridviews, and they both share the **same** datasource. I have chosen to only show the first n columns on my first dgv, and the rest n columns of my datasource on the second dgv like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mytable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].Visible = i < n;
            dataGridView2.Columns[i].Visible = i >= n;
        }
```

**Introduction**: I want to right click and move columns from one datagridview to another at will. I do this by making the respective columns visible and not visible, since both datagridviews share the same datasource. I have run into problems concerning column indices of course.

Consider this example: I have a datatable of 5 columns, and I give that datasource to both my datagridviews. I decide to make the first 3 columns of the datatable visible on the first datagridvew, and the two remaining columns visible on the second. Now, if I wanted to move a column from the second datagridview to the first, I would first fire this event:

```
private void dataGridView2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var ht = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            currentColumnIndex = ht.ColumnIndex;

            if ((ht.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader))
            {

                contextMenuStrip2.Show(MousePosition);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have made it so that this will only show the context menu if the user has right clicked on a column header. Then, throught the contextmenu this happens:

```
 private void moveToFirstGridToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView2.Columns[currentColumnIndex+dataGridView1.Columns.GetColumnCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[currentColumnIndex + dataGridView1.Columns.GetColumnCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)].Visible = true;
        currentColumnIndex = -5;
    }
```

currentColumnIndex is a global variable which was to track the index of the column the user right clicked on.

**Problem**: The problem is that this currentColumnIndex gets the index of the current datagridview's index, and not the whole dataset. In my example, if I go to the second dgv and right click the header of the second column, currentColumnIndex shows 1 instead of 4, which would be the correct global index. This leads to problems later on, when you for example move the second column first, and then the first one.

I believe it is important to have a way to know the **correct global** index of my columns. I wasn't sure whether this can be achieved, so I thought that maybe I could look for column names, since all the column names of my dataset will be unique. The question then is how to get the header column text when you right click on it, given the structure I have.

The question could have been much shorter, just including the last sentence of the last paragraph, but I wanted to give more accurate view of what is going on.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the control (datagridview), but with how you manage your specific situation (2 levels of indexing in this case). You have written a lot (what shows a right attitude: kudos), although the result is not too positive as far as the actual problem is not clear. In fact you seem to get this point in your last sentence (but no result...). The main goal here is making a clear and appealing enough description (i.e., one easily attracting many potential helpers); you have to prove the difficulty and that you tried something, but not by making it so big and unclear...

Comment: ...If you redefine (and tag) this question properly, I am sure that you will quickly get good help. This is not a datagridview problem, but a data-storage/-structure, algorithm, etc. one. Describe the problem clearly, together with what you tried and the problems you found; you shouldn't need more than 1 third of the length of the current version.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I think I found a quicker solution to this however. Posting it now.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with my suggestion (IMO, it doesn't even represent a good enough solution and seriously doubt that any future reader will find it useful. Basically, you created a problem which wasn't required by coming up with a non-ideal configuration; you kept that problem and came up with a slight correction which didn't correct the underlying wrong approach), but completely up to you.

Comment: Can you help me then understand how to improve my approach? What is a better way to do this?

Comment: I told you: this is not a datagridview problem, but a data-storage/algorithm one. Once you face this problem right, you can maximise datagridview (or any other control). Rather than facing the problem in this way (and asking here about how to solve the way in which you faced the problem, regardless of datagridview), you adapted you approach to your (limited) knowledge of the datagridview control. You have to create algorithms/data-structures easily accessible/scalable/modifiable independently upon the GUI element you are relying on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question: **This will just solve the problem I described I had currently. It doesn't actually answer the question at the top. which is how to find the column name by right clicking**.  However it shouldn't be a problem getting the name and column info that you need when you actually have the correct index: dataGridView1.Columns[i]...

Solution of my problem:

It seems I don't need to look for a way of detecting the column names. Instead of using the DataGridViewi_MouseDown events, I now use the **dataGridViewi_ColumnHeaderMouseClick** which uses the DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs class. So I moved the code from the former event to the latter. Now, whenever you use e.ColumnIndex, you actually get the **correct** index, meaning the index of the whole datatable and not just the current datagridview's index.

To make this work I also change the code for making columns visible. Now it's just:

```
private void moveToFirstGridToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView2.Columns[currentColumnIndex].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[currentColumnIndex].Visible = true;
        currentColumnIndex = -5;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Find column name/header via right click:

```
Private Sub dgv1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgv1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        MsgBox(e.ColumnIndex & " " & dgv1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name & " " & dgv1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText)
    End If
End Sub
```